# How let users to access requirejs modules outside main?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm implementing an AMD module oriented js framework that will be used on third party sites.

With this line, framework users will configure necessary modules

```
<script data-main="/main.js" src="/require.js"></script>
```

The problem is that `data-main` reference is loaded asynchronously so any js logic depending on modules loaded by `main.js` would fail unless I can be sure that it finished loading.

I'm pretty new to requirejs so not sure what's the good practices to create a framework that will be used by other people.

How could resolve this very simple problem?

**EDIT**
An example to explain my point

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min',
    }
});
```

**main js reference + extra code**

```
 <script data-main="/main.js" src="/require.js"></script>
 <script>
    require(['jquery'], function($) {
        // since main.js is not loaded yet, it will assume that there is a jquery.js 
        // file on the same folder that this file
        console.log('myModule was also loaded and can use jQuery');
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Take a look at the last 20-30 lines of jQuery and see if that helps you.

Comment: @squid314: I'm afraid I don't understand how that helps in my particular case. Could you explain? Thanks :)

Comment: Thinking again, maybe I had it backwards. jQuery, though not strictly intending to be part of a Require pipeline, includes code to expose itself to the Require pipeline. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @Louis: replaced `define` by `require`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to depend on other libraries and are specifically targeting being in a Require pipeline, all you need to do is to declare some dependencies with

```
define(
    'myModule',    // module name
    ['foo'],       // module dependencies
    function(foo){ // module construction
        var myModule = {};

        .... code to set up the module ....

        return myModule;
    });
```

and Require will take care of things. This will register your module with Require and won't attempt to build your module until all of your dependencies are available. This functionality is discussed [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/why.html#9).

**Update with example**

Require JS is designed to work both with and without a prebuilt configuration. The `paths` property of the Require config object only provides Require with information on how to attempt to find libraries which have not yet been registered. However, the registration and then dependency resolution is handled by Require regardless of how/where the module was registered. Please see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hD6f/3/) for a working example of how you *can* register and use dependencies.

**Update 2 regarding config**

Since RequireJS loads everything asynchronously, you are correct, your code example will not work. However, you're making an incorrect assumption about how it is "supposed" to work. You have an incorrect example of what your library's clients' Require configuration will look like. If someone else is building an application using RequireJS and they want to use your library, they should declare the path to your library in their `require.config`:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        // this tells require how to load jQuery (a library maintained neither by you nor your clients).
        'jquery': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min',
        // this tells require how to load myModule (the library you are building for your clients).
        'myModule': '//example.com/js/my-module.min',
        // this tells require how to load foo (a library built and hosted by your clients).
        'foo': 'scripts/foo'
    }
});
```

On the other hand, if your clients *can't* update their Require config to include your library in the declarations, then you're out of luck. All you can do is take all of your dependencies and bundle them up in your distribution file and then declare no dependencies:

```
define(
    'myModule',
    [], // can't declare any dependencies
    function() {
        // these dependencies are inside of the definition function to keep the global namespace clean
        // since we need jQuery, we have to inline it:
        var jQuery = ....
        // same goes for d3.js
        var d3 = ....

        // now we can set up the module itself
        var myModule = {};
        .... code to set up the module ....
        return myModule;
    }
);
```

Obviously, this option means that you can't use the libraries which are being used by your clients. This means your library will be a lot heavier and include effectively duplicate code and data.

Hope that helps you understand how Require works and how other people will use your library.

Comment: Good answer, that's what I was going to say.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, where would you put that code?... if I put that code inmediatly after `<script data-main="/main.js" src="/require.js"></script>` is not gona work... or yes? main.js is loaded async so any code added later need to take into account

Comment: Perhaps you need to read up a little more on how RequireJS and its dependency system work. Here, you call the `define` function, which is part of Require. That function will not invoke your module construction function until its dependencies are available. The `define` function is provided by `require.js`, not by `main.js`.

Comment: @squid314: I might be confused but my requirejs configuration (where I specify paths for modules, in your case `myModule` and `foo`) is inside `main.js`. How that could work if requirejs configurations are not yet loaded. Maybe you could add the complete template for your solution to work. Thanks

Comment: Please see my updated answer and example @TimmyO'Tool . I'm pretty sure that it is possible to just add your library file after the `require.js` script tag.

Comment: +1 for the effort and patience. Thanks. Please see my edit on this question and let me know yot thoughts.

Comment: Ah, @TimmyO'Tool, I see your point (also discussed [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main)). I think you may be confused as to how the users of your library will reference it. Updating my answer again based on your updates.

Comment: @squid314: I've added an answer with the approach I finally followed. Thanks for your time! Feel free to integrate my answer to yours so I can give you credit for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally used this approach

```
<script src="http://mydomain/js/require.js"></script>
<script>
requirejs.config({  
    baseUrl: 'http://mydomain/js' 
});
require(['main'],function(){
    // here users can do anything they want as all required libraries are loaded
});
</script>
```

`main.js` is loaded with a `require` instruction instead of using `data-main` attribute from script tag , this provides a callback where users can put their code.